# Rate-limited event handler in erlang/OTP

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a data source that produces point at a potentially high rate, and I'd like to perform a possibly time-consuming operation on each point; but I would also like the system to degrade gracefully when it becomes overloaded, by dropping excess data points.

As far as I can tell, using a gen_event will never skip events. Conceptually, what I would like the gen_event to do is to drop all but the latest pending events before running the handlers again.

Is there a way to do this with standard OTP ? or is there a good reason why I should not handle things that way ?

So far the best I have is using a gen_server and relying on the timeout to trigger the expensive events:

```
-behaviour(gen_server).
init() -> 
    {ok, Pid} = gen_event:start_link(),
    {ok, {Pid, none}}.

handle_call({add, H, A},_From,{Pid,Data}) ->
    {reply, gen_event:add_handler(Pid,H,A), {Pid,Data}}.

handle_cast(Data,{Pid,_OldData}) -> 
    {noreply, {Pid,Data,0}}.  % set timeout to 0 

handle_info(timeout, {Pid,Data}) ->
    gen_event:sync_notify(Pid,Data),
    {noreply, {Pid,Data}}.
```

Is this approach correct ? (esp. with respect to supervision ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this with standard OTP ?

No.

> is there a good reason why I should not handle things that way ?

No, timing out early can increase the performance of the entire system. Read about how [here](http://ferd.ca/rtb-where-erlang-blooms.html).

> Is this approach correct ? (esp. with respect to supervision ? )

No idea, you haven't provided the supervision code.

---

As a bit of extra information to your first question:

If you can use 3rd party libraries outside of OTP, there are a few out there that can add preemptive timeouts, which is what you are describing.

There are two that I am familiar with the first is [dispcount](https://github.com/ferd/dispcount/), and the second is [chick](https://github.com/DBarney/chick) (I'm the author of chick, i'll try not to advertise the project here).

Dispcount works really good for single resources that only have a limited number of jobs that can be run at the same time and does no queuing. you can read about it [here](http://ferd.ca/rtb-where-erlang-blooms.html) (**warning** lots of really interesting information!).

Dispcount didn't work for me because i would have had to spawn 4000+ pools of processes to handle the amount of different queues inside of my app. I wrote chick because I needed a way to dynamically increase and decrease my queue length, as well as being able to queue up requests and deny others, without having to spawn 4000+ pools of processes.

If I were you I would try out discount first (as most solutions do not need chick), and then if you need something a bit more dynamic then a pool that can respond to a certain number of requests try out chick.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on supervision, but I would implement this as a queue with expiring items.

I've implemented something that you can use below.

I made it a gen_server; when you create it you give it a maximum age for old items.

Its interface is that you can send it items to be processed and you can request items that have not been dequeued  It records the time at which it receives every item.  Every time it receives an item to be processed, it checks all the items in the queue, dequeueing and discarding those that are older than the maximum age.  (If you want the maximum age to be always respected, you can filter the queue before you return queued items)

Your data source will cast data (`{process_this, Anything}`) to the work queue and your (potentially slow) consumers process will call (`gimme`) to get data.

```
-module(work_queue).
-behavior(gen_server).

-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_call/3]).

init(DiscardAfter) ->
  {ok, {DiscardAfter, queue:new()}}.

handle_cast({process_this, Data}, {DiscardAfter, Queue0}) ->
  Instant = now(),
  Queue1 = queue:filter(fun({Stamp, _}) -> not too_old(Stamp, Instant, DiscardAfter) end, Queue0),
  Queue2 = queue:in({Instant, Data}, Queue1),
  {noreply, {DiscardAfter, Queue2}}.

handle_call(gimme, From, State = {DiscardAfter, Queue0}) ->
  case queue:is_empty(Queue0) of
    true ->
      {reply, no_data, State};
    false ->
      {{value, {_Stamp, Data}}, Queue1} = queue:out(Queue0),
      {reply, {data, Data}, {DiscardAfter, Queue1}}
  end.

delta({Mega1, Unit1, Micro1}, {Mega2, Unit2, Micro2}) ->
  ((Mega2 - Mega1) * 1000000 + Unit2 - Unit1) * 1000000 + Micro2 - Micro1.

too_old(Stamp, Instant, DiscardAfter) ->
  delta(Stamp, Instant) > DiscardAfter.
```

Little demo at the REPL:

```
c(work_queue).
{ok, PidSrv} = gen_server:start(work_queue, 10 * 1000000, []).         
gen_server:cast(PidSrv, {process_this, <<"going_to_go_stale">>}),      
timer:sleep(11 * 1000),                                                
gen_server:cast(PidSrv, {process_this, <<"going to push out previous">>}),
{gen_server:call(PidSrv, gimme), gen_server:call(PidSrv, gimme)}.
```

Comment: "a .. queue of worker processes waiting for data", this doesn't sound like Erlang at all.  One of the advantages of Erlang is that it is cheap to spawn new processes and terminated them on work done.  You could just count the number of running workers in the gen_server to avoid overload situation.  Or even easier: have the processes shoot themselves if they are still around. Multiple worker processes however would only help you on SMP machines.

Comment: Excellent point.  I've had "processes waiting for data" on the brain recently but there's absolutely no need to use them here.  What do you think of the rest of the answer?

Comment: I may not have fully understood everything but I think this solves a different problem. I don't want to commit to a fixed DiscardAfter interval. Maybe a different way of stating it is that I want the result of my processing to always reflect the most recent data point I know about, without wasting time on processing obsolete data. But the amount of processing required may vary dynamically, and so may the data rate of the source.

Comment: Yeah, I felt like I didn't understand exactly what problem you wanted to solve-- I think it's a little clearer now, but I still wouldn't be able to precisely define what you want to achieve.  Do you want to only process data in order? When is data "obsolete"?  Part of solving a problem like this is defining it unambiguously.